# Cannot Connect to Personal Bank Account via Plaid API

Tags: python, plaid

I'm trying to connect to my personal bank account through plaid.

I first tried to use the sandbox code (https://dashboard.plaid.com/overview/sandbox) directly but through this I can only connect to the dummy data in sandbox (using username: user_good & password: pass_good).

But when I try to connect to  my Bank of America account I receive an error that my credentials are incorrect.

I then modified the boiler code for the sandbox environment (by switching `PLAID_ENV=sandbox` to `PLAID_ENV=development` and switching the `PLAID_CLIENT_ID=xxxx` & `PLAID_SECRET=xxxxx` provided in the sandbox code linked above to my personal dev keys) and launching **server.py** but this is gives me an error that my api keys are invalid.

Could someone please understand the steps I need to take to modify the sandbox code to directly log into my personal account?

Comment: This is a question for the API provider, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If the error says your keys are invalid, then that's probably the problem.  You need Development environment keys and you need to have requested Development environment access.  It's unclear from the question whether the key you're using is a Sandbox key or a Development key?

P.S. Even if it is a Sandbox key, please don't post your secret keys on Stack Overflow!  Since your key has been compromised by being made publicly available, you should rotate it via the [Dashboard](https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/keys) as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi Alex - thanks for the heads up on the API keys. I'm following the instructions here in the quickstart https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/.

Comment: ```git clone https://github.com/plaid/quickstart.git \
cd quickstart/python \

pip install -r requirements.txt \


PLAID_CLIENT_ID='CLIENT_ID' \
PLAID_SECRET='SECRET' \
PLAID_ENV='sandbox' \
PLAID_PRODUCTS='transactions' \
PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES='US' \
python server.py```

Comment: When I use my sandbox keys and run the above it works just fine. But when I use my development keys and switch PLAID_ENV='development' I get the invalid key error when I hope the app in my browser.

Comment: Can you help me understand why this is? And should I be able to log into my personal bank account in the sandbox environment? Currently in sandbox I can only log into Plaids dummy account but I am not able to log into my own personal account (I get an error that my credentials are incorrect).